# scraping when there is a drop down box

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to scrape data from the following website: https://electproject.github.io/Early-Vote-2020G/SC.html

I can scrape the first cleanly with the following code:

```
require(xml2)
require(rvest)
require(janitor)
require(tidyverse)

link <- "https://electproject.github.io/Early-Vote-2020G/SC.html"
raw_webpage <- read_html(link)
html_table(raw_webpage, fill = TRUE)[[1]]
```

However, the second table in the page with county level information has me stumped. Would someone know how to scrape in `r`:

1. Select 100 in the `Show Entries` drop down box
2. Scrape all the county level details

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the webpage, this data is displayed using `DataTables` which is a javascript plugin and can't be interacted with directly using `rvest`.  Fortunately, the data is loaded with the page and can be extracted directly from the htmlwidget:

```
library(rvest)
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

link <- "https://electproject.github.io/Early-Vote-2020G/SC.html"
raw_webpage <- read_html(link)

json_dat <- raw_webpage %>%
  html_node(xpath = "//script[@data-for='htmlwidget-0ecc3fac592e3c6771ab']") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  fromJSON()

json_dat %>% 
  purrr::pluck("x", "data") %>%
  t() %>%
  as_tibble(.name_repair = "minimal") %>%
  set_names(json_dat %>% 
              purrr::pluck("x", "container") %>%
              read_html() %>%
              html_table() %>%
              map(names) %>%
              unlist()) %>%
  mutate(across(-1, as.numeric))

# A tibble: 46 x 4
   County        `Mail Ballots Requested` `Mail Ballot Returned` `Percent Returned`
   <chr>                            <dbl>                  <dbl>              <dbl>
 1 01-ABBEVILLE                      4617                   4392              0.951
 2 02-AIKEN                         31520                  28028              0.889
 3 03-ALLENDALE                      1836                   1701              0.926
 4 04-ANDERSON                      26596                  22574              0.849
 5 05-BAMBERG                        2609                   2417              0.926
 6 06-BARNWELL                       4007                   3661              0.914
 7 07-BEAUFORT                      47448                  41409              0.873
 8 08-BERKELEY                      42517                  37657              0.886
 9 09-CALHOUN                        2985                   2704              0.906
10 10-CHARLESTON                   122073                 105124              0.861
# ... with 36 more rows
```

To expand this into a function to scrape the states that are available, you can generate a list of links and iterate over them:

```
links <- set_names(paste0("https://electproject.github.io/Early-Vote-2020G/", state.abb, ".html"), state.name)

states_dat <- imap(links[8:12], ~ {
  tryCatch({
    
    raw_webpage <- read_html(.x)
    
    # Get html widget ID
    hw_id <- raw_webpage %>%
      html_node("div.datatables") %>%
      html_attr("id")
    
    json_dat <- raw_webpage %>%
      html_node(xpath = paste0("//script[@data-for='", hw_id, "']")) %>%
      html_text() %>%
      fromJSON()
    
    json_dat %>%
      purrr::pluck("x", "data") %>%
      t() %>%
      as_tibble(.name_repair = "minimal") %>%
      set_names(
        json_dat %>%
          purrr::pluck("x", "container") %>%
          read_html() %>%
          html_table() %>%
          map(names) %>%
          unlist()
      ) %>%
      mutate(across(-1, as.numeric))
  },
  error = function(e)
    paste(.y, "data not available:", e))
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution. Just in case, if the data was not loaded with the page and instead it fetched the data based on the drop down, then how would one solve the problem?

Comment: Is there an easier way to figure out `xpath`

Comment: You would need to use a (more complicated) webdriver approach (e.g. Selenium or PhantomJS).  Can you clarify your second question?

Comment: When I copy xpath using firefox it comes out as `//*[@id="htmlwidget-0ecc3fac592e3c6771ab"]`, which is different to the correct path as in your answer.

Comment: Did you want me to show how to get the ID programmatically?  I assume you're trying to scrape all 50 states.

Comment: See edit - I noted that not every state had this table available.

Comment: Mate that is just unreal! Thank you so much for this!!!